# Using R to eliminate duplicates in a very large table and then use the remaining data to calculate the distance between several points

Tags: r, duplicates

I have an example.csv file that looks like this (but very large, >200 MB):

```
FI  SI  GT  ED  FPx Fpy
1       F   8   30  32
    1   S   17      
2       F   3   34  64
2       F   3   34  64
    2   S   100     
    2   S   100     
    2   S   100     
    2   S   100     
    2   S   100     
    2   S   100     
3       F   33  53  22
3       F   33  53  22
    3   S   50      
    3   S   50      
    3   S   50      
        U   33      
4       U   3       
5       F   3   9   37
        U   3   1   12
        S   3       
    4   U   17  1   12
6       F   3   3   53
6       F   3   3   53
```

First, I need to eliminate the duplicates in both FI and SI columns. I've tried to use `unique()` and `setkey()`, but they seem to work for eliminating duplicates in just one column. So, my question is: how can I process both columns at once?

Second, after eliminating duplicates, I need to use the remaining data on columns FPx and FPy to calculate the distance between each coordinate (x,y) and the immediately following coordinate, i.e. the square root of [(FPx2-FPx1)^2+(FPy2-FPy1)^2], but only when the entries appear in the same row as F (in column GT) and the cell immediately below F is S. For example, I need the distance between (34,64) and (30,32), but not between (1,12) and (9,37).

I also need the results as a new table and as a mean multiplied by 0.264583333.

Making it clearer:

The above table without duplicates should look like this:

```
FI  SI  GT  ED  FPx Fpy
1       F   8   30  32
    1   S   17      
2       F   3   34  64
    2   S   100     
3       F   33  53  22
    3   S   50      
4       U   3       
5       F   3   9   37
    4   U   3       
6       F   3   3   53
```

As for the second part of my question, the table would look like this:

```
FI  SI  GT  ED  FPx Fpy Dist    Dist*0.264583333
1       F   8   30  32  32,24903099 8,532556106
    1   S   17              
2       F   3   34  64  46,09772229 12,19668901
    2   S   100             
3       F   33  53  22  46,4865572  12,29956824
    3   S   50              
4       U   3               
5       F   3   9   37      
    4   U   3               
6       F   3   3   53
```

Column `Dist.` refers to the distance of one F coordinate to the next, provided that the cells between one F and the other contains an S (F and S refer to values in the third column GT). So I have the distance between (30,32) and (34,64), (53,22) and (34,64), and (9,37) and (53,22). Notice that I don't need the distances between the last and the second to last Fs, because there is an U between them, but no S. Notice also that I need the distances between the coordinates as they appear in the original file, that is, keeping the order/sequence of them. In Excel, the formula would be something like this `=SQRT((F4-F2)^2+(E4-E2)^2)`.

Comment: We need some things too.  Please show what you've tried, and where it went wrong, and the desired result you expect.

Comment: A `dput` of a `head` of the data.table would be helpful, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's additional `data.table` approach (assuming `df` is your data)

```
library(data.table)
DT <- unique(setDT(df), by = c("FI", "SI")) # Removing duplicates
DT[GT == "F" | GT == "S", indx2 := paste0(GT, c(as.character(GT[2]), as.character(GT[.I - 1])))] # Creating an index of consecutive "FS"
DT[indx2 == "FS", Dist := c(as.matrix(dist(cbind(FPx, Fpy)))[cbind(seq_len(.N - 1) + 1, seq_len(.N - 1))], NA)] # Calculating distances
DT[!is.na(Dist), Dist2 := Dist * 0.264583333] # Calculating your second column
DT
#    FI SI GT  ED FPx Fpy indx2     Dist     Dist2
# 1:  1     F   8  30  32    FS 32.24903  8.532556
# 2:     1  S  17            SF       NA        NA
# 3:  2     F   3  34  64    FS 46.09772 12.196689
# 4:     2  S 100            SF       NA        NA
# 5:  3     F  33  53  22    FS 46.48656 12.299568
# 6:     3  S  50            SF       NA        NA
# 7:        U  33            NA       NA        NA
# 8:  4     U   3            NA       NA        NA
# 9:  5     F   3   9  37    FS       NA        NA
#10:     4  U  17   1  12    NA       NA        NA
#11:  6     F   3   3  53    FF       NA        NA
```

**Edit:** Attaching the data set I've used

```
df <- structure(list(FI = c("1", "", "2", "2", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "3", "3", "", "", "", "", "4", "5", "", "", "", "6", "6"), 
    SI = c("", "1", "", "", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "", 
    "", "3", "3", "3", "", "", "", "", "", "4", "", ""), GT = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("F", "S", "U"), class = "factor"), 
    ED = c(8L, 17L, 3L, 3L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 
    33L, 33L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 33L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 17L, 3L, 3L
    ), FPx = c("30", "", "34", "34", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
    "53", "53", "", "", "", "", "", "9", "1", "", "1", "3", "3"
    ), Fpy = c("32", "", "64", "64", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
    "22", "22", "", "", "", "", "", "37", "12", "", "12", "53", 
    "53")), .Names = c("FI", "SI", "GT", "ED", "FPx", "Fpy"), row.names = c(NA, 
-23L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: David, I can't see what I did wrong. My indx2 column returns `SS SS SS SS NA FS FF FF NA FF`, and I get only `NA` as a result for Dist, and consequently no Dist2 column.

Comment: For what data? The data you've provided? See my edit, I've attached the data set I've used

Comment: I see, but how can I do that without recreating my data? I've provided a small example, but my table is really large. The problem is, as far as I could understand, that when I apply `unique`, the table is rearranged, and everything gets messy afterwards.

Comment: Then you should provide a reproducible example, i.e., a data set that represents your real data good enough in order to solve the problem. My solution worked perfectly fine on you data set. When you apply `unique`, your data isn't getting rearranged. It is only gets rearranged if you apply `setkey`, which I didn't do

Comment: David, your last answer solved the problem. I was setting keys at the first place when reading the table. Now it works perfectly. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to using the `data.table` package, this is very easy.

```
require(data.table)
setDT(yourdata)

yourdata <- unique(yourdata)
```

This would look for row duplicates using all columns, not just one column,

Try `?data.table::unique` for more details. You might also be interested in the `duplicated` function.

For the second part of your question, I recommend using the `dist` function. Very fast.

```
#Recreate your data
FT <- c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5,5,6)
SI <- c(NA,1,NA,2,NA,3,NA,NA,4,NA) 
GT <- c("F","S","F","S","F","S","U","F","U","F")
ED <- c(8,17,3,100,33,50,3,3,3,3)
FPx <- c(30,NA,34,NA,53,NA,NA,9,NA,3) 
FPy <- c(32,NA,64,NA,22,NA,NA,37,NA,53)
data <- data.table(FT,SI,GT,ED,FPx,FPy)

#Group and Index data
grouped.data <- data[ , list(SI=max(SI,na.rm=T),GT=paste0(GT,collapse=""),
    ED=list(ED),FPx=max(FPx,na.rm=T),FPy=max(FPy,na.rm=T)), by=FT]
grouped.data[ , idx := .I]

#Calculate distance
grouped.data[ , dist.xy := sqrt((FPx[idx]-FPx[idx+1])^2+(FPy[idx]-FPy[idx+1])^2)]

#Relabel rows that do not meet your criteria
grouped.data[GT!="FS", dist.xy := NA]
grouped.data[dist.xy==Inf, dist.xy := NA]
```

And the resulting data looks like this:

```
   FT   SI GT      ED  FPx  FPy idx  dist.xy
1:  1    1 FS    8,17   30   32   1 32.24903
2:  2    2 FS   3,100   34   64   2 46.09772
3:  3    3 FS   33,50   53   22   3       NA
4:  4 -Inf  U       3 -Inf -Inf   4       NA
5:  5    4 FU     3,3    9   37   5       NA
6:  6 -Inf  F       3    3   53   6       NA
```

Comment: Mike.Gahan, I managed to solve my first problem. But for the second, I really I don't have skills enough to do that. I have also seen an interesting example using `ddply` from the `plyr` package `[link](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/52437/calculate-distance-between-x-y-coordinates-by-individual-in-r)`.

Comment: f you provide expected input and expected output for a small sample of your data, I am pretty sure this is a manageable problem for Stack Overflow. I attempted to guess what you wanted in my edited answer, but it is not completely clear from your question.

Comment: Hi, Mike.Gaham. I provided some extra information. I hope it's clearer now. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: It works fine, except for the expected row:  `3       F   33  53  22  46,4865572  12,29956824`. I tried using the original table, and it works too.  I can't recreate the data, since the actual table is too large -- would it really be a problem? I can't understand why you said I should recreate the data.